# Custom password field with devise (ruby)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, rubygems

I'm using a database shared between 2 rails apps.

A webapp using BCrypt and has_secure_password to authenticate user, and my app, an REST API, using Devise to authenticate users. Password hash is the same.

So, I would like to use the field password_digest instead of encrypted_password to authenticate via Devise and I don't know how ! (I'm seeking in the documentation but find nothing). So, I have to copy / paste my password hash from password_digest to encrypted_password yet.

Here my session controller Code :

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

before_filter :ensure_params_exist

def create
    build_resource
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(:email => params[:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(params[:password])
        #resource.ensure_authentication_token!  #make sure the user has a token generated
        sign_in("user", resource)
        render :json => { :authentication_token => resource.authentication_token, :lastname => resource.lastname, :firstname => resource.firstname, :last_sign_in => resource.last_sign_in_at }, :status => :created
    return
    end
    invalid_login_attempt
end

#def destroy
#   # expire auth token
#   @user=User.where(:authentication_token=>params[:auth_token]).first
#   @user.reset_authentication_token!
#   render :json => { :message => ["Session deleted."] },  :success => true, :status => :ok
#end


protected
    def ensure_params_exist
        return unless params[:email].blank?
        render :json=>{:success=>false, :message=>"missing email parameter"}, :status=>422
    end

    def invalid_login_attempt
        warden.custom_failure!
        render :json => { :errors => ["Invalid email or password."] },  :success => false, :status => :unauthorized
    end
```

end

And then my User Model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :ensure_authentication_token
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable, :token_authenticatable#, :registerable,
         #:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :client_id, :firstname, :group_id, :lastname, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id, :group_ids, :auth_token, :password_digest, :encrypted_password

  # Relations dans la base de données
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :role

  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships



end
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware about how BCrypt/has_secure_password works, but you can either 
use virtual attributes as follows

```
def encrypted_password
 return password_digest
end

def encrypted_password= value
 return password_digest
end
```

Or even better, use alias methods
set encrypted_password and encrypted_password= as alias methods for password_digest and password_digest=.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Where should I place this code ? I tried in my User Model, but it return an error, and in my Sessions controller, authentication not work if I try this code. Thanks

Comment: yes in the user model. And what error did you get? You mentioned something about copying and pasting the password_digest into the encrypted password to work. A little detail on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get this work is to use `alias_attribute`. This problem might be resolved a long time ago but I still want to come up with this.

```rb
alias_attribute :encrypted_password, :password_digest
```